# Command to auto remove closed apps from the MacOS dock on Mojave?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, dock

In previous versions of MacOS you could issue:

`defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool TRUE; killall Dock`

to auto-remove closed apps form the dock even without quitting them.

This doesn't seem to work on Mojave 10.14.4. Any Idea what the modification would be? Or if it's still possible?